# Need help understanding the gain on antenna pattern plots

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, radiation-pattern

My understanding is that the value of the axis (like `-10 / 0 dB`) refers to the maximum antenna gain (e.g. `12dbi`).

So, if a point on the figure is `-5dB`, then antenna gain of that point is

`12 - 5 = 7 dBi`.

Is this correct?

The axes in the figure are in degrees and dB.

[image: db]

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the outer ring in the polar plot would be 12 dBi. So you are correct in thinking that any point -5 dB from the outer ring would represent a gain of 7 dBi.

It works the same for referencing dB, dBi (isotropic), and dBd (dipole).

Comment: More detailed information about pattern plots can be found [here](http://online-telecom-exhibition.blogspot.com/2013/09/antenna-definitions.html).

Comment: Also, since Mike mentions dBi and dBd, remember that 0dBd = 2.15dBi. So if you see one, and need to convert to the other, that's all you need to note.

Comment: Thank you so much !! haha !! first time I did not notice the db in the figure